# Return JSON response using Django template system

Tags: json, django

Is it possible?
I tried:

```
def jsonview(request):
  context = {}
  context['date'] = datetime.now()
  return render(request, "json.html", context, content_type="application/json")
```

The json.html file:

```
{% load i18n %}

'{"date": "{{ date|escapejs }}", "test": "hello"}'
```

The response is:

```
'\n\n{"date": "2014\u002D11\u002D13 11:58:31.635102", "test": "hello"}'
```

so the error is :

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 3 column 1 of the JSON data
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this, rather than building it up as a dictionary in the view and using `json.dumps()`?

Comment: To take advantage of the django templating. You cannot dumps a datetime object but you should first reproduce what the django templating do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple approach is to render first the data from your template to string and response it as json like the sample code below.

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.http import HttpResponse
def jsonview(request):
      context = {}
      context['data'] = render_to_string("json.html", {'date': datetime.now()})
      return HttpResponse(json.dumps(context), content_type="application/json")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Django templatetags. You can create your own [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) or use [built-in ones](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/)

In this case you could use `templatetag now` in your json.html file:

```
{% now "SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT" %}
```