# Have to refresh the page before my ajax request happens to text in django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I have follow button which works by using ajax the `{{ total_followers }}` works well by increasing or decreasing upon a click but the *follow* and *unfollow* buttons change only when I refresh the whole page which is what I do not want

**My views**

```
@ajax_required
@require_POST
@login_required
def user_follow(request):
    user_id = request.POST.get('id')
    action = request.POST.get('action')
    if user_id and action:
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
            if action == 'follow':
                Contact.objects.get_or_create(user_from=request.user,user_to=user)
            else:
                Contact.objects.filter(user_from=request.user,user_to=user).delete()
            return JsonResponse({'status':'ok'})
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return JsonResponse({'status':'ok'})
    return JsonResponse({'status':'ok'})
```

*My HTML*

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load thumbnail %}

{% block title %}{{ user.get_full_name }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>{{ user.get_full_name }}</h1>
<div class="profile-info">
    {% thumbnail user.profile.photo '180x180' crop='100%' as im %}
    <img src="{{ im.url }}" alt="profile photo">
    {% endthumbnail %}
</div>
{% with total_followers=user.followers.count %}
<span class="count">
    <span class="total">{{ total_followers }}</span>
    follower{{ total_followers|pluralize }}
</span>

<a href="#" data-id='{{ user.id }}' data-action='{%  if request.user in user.followers.all %}un{% endif %}follow' class="follow button">
    {% if request.user not in user.followers.all %}
    Follow
    {% else %}
    Unfollow
    {% endif %}
</a>

<div id="image-list" class="image-container">
    {% include "images/image/list_ajax.html" with images=user.images_created.all %}
</div>
{% endwith %}
{% endblock %}

{% block domready %}
$('a.follow').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$.post('{% url "user_follow" %}',
{
id: $(this).data('id'),
action: $(this).data('action')
},
function(data){
if (data['status'] == 'ok') {
var previous_action = $('a.follow').data('action');
// toggle data-action
$('a.follow').data('action',
previous_action == 'follow' ? 'unfollow' : 'follow');

// update total followers
var previous_followers = parseInt(
$('span.count .total').text());
$('span.count .total').text(previous_action == 'follow' ?
previous_followers + 1 : previous_followers - 1);
}
}
);
});
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return **html** template code dynamically from **view** when you called from **ajax** and replace that **html** with previous with current **html** that you will get in **success**() method of **ajax**.

Follow this answer
[Return JSON response using Django template system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26358284/return-json-response-using-django-template-system?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

**Edit:**

Make a template that should have html code that you want to change when ajax request called.

```
html = render_to_string("yourtemplate.html", context_object)
return JsonResponse({'status':'ok', 'html':html})
```

**Template:**

```
   new_html = data['html']
   $selector = $('#id of block');
   $selector.html(new_html);
```

Comment: WIth this example do I have to write an entire new view for this function?

Comment: No need to write new view, add extra in already exist code. check my updated answer